# Menú cuenta vocales

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Estoy realizando un proyecto con codeblocks en el cual debo crear un menú con tres opciones, 1. ingresar frases, 2. contar vocales con y sin tildes y 3. resultados. En la primera opción debo crear un contador para llevar la cuenta de cada frase que ingrese. En la segunda opción debo mostrar en pantalla la última frase escrita y cuantas vocales tiene. Y en la tercera opción debo mostrar la cantidad de palabras ingresadas y la cantidad total de vocales contabilizadas. Mi problema con el código es que no logro crear un contador funcional para llevar la cuenta de las frases, tampoco logro guardar las palabras ingresadas para mostrarla en pantalla. Estoy utilizando void pero tampoco logro invocar la información guardada en los otros dos void. Alguien me puede ayudar. Esta es una parte del código:

```
void frases()
{
     system ("cls");

     setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
                int cont=1;
                int vo_a=0, vo_e=0, vo_i=0, vo_o=0, vo_u=0, contvocal=0;

                cout << "Ingrese una frase: " << endl;
                cin.ignore(110, '\n');
                cin.getline(palabra,100);
                cont++;
                for (int i=0; i<strlen(palabra); i++) /.
                {
                   switch(palabra[i])
                   {
                       
                       case 'a': vo_a++;
                       break;
                       case 'e': vo_e++;
                       break;
                       case 'i': vo_i++;
                       break;
                       case 'o': vo_o++;
                       break;
                       case 'u': vo_u++;
                       break;
                   }
                   contvocal=vo_a+vo_e+vo_i+vo_o+vo_u;
                }
                cout << "TOTAL GENERAL DE VOCALES: " << contvocal << endl;
                cout << " " << endl;
}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Menú contador de vocales y oraciones C++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/605752/men%c3%ba-contador-de-vocales-y-oraciones-c)

Answer (score 0):

Cada símbolo tiene su propio código. Por ejemplo la **a** es distinta a la **á** y así con las demás vocales.

Para facilitar el cálculo, puedes crear una función que cuente las letras que le pases en otra palabra:

```
int contar(const wstring& palabra, const wstring& letras){
    int cantidad = 0;
    for (const wchar_t letra : letras)
        cantidad += count(palabra.begin(), palabra.end(), letra);
    return cantidad;
}
```

Y en la función `main` solo tienes que llamar esa función con cada lista de caracteres que consideres **a**, **e**, **i**, **o** y **u**.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

wstring palabra;

cout << "Ingrese una frase: " << endl;
getline(wcin, palabra);

vo_a = contar(palabra, L"aá");
vo_e = contar(palabra, L"eé");
vo_i = contar(palabra, L"ií");
vo_o = contar(palabra, L"oó");
vo_u = contar(palabra, L"uúü");
```

Por cierto, en lugar de `char` es conveniente usar `wchar_t` porque estos caracteres especiales ocupan 2 bytes en UTF-8. De esta forma puedes compararlos fácilmente.

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##bVPJbtswEL3rKwYqUMiIa7jXyArgpEZRQEiANujVGEsThalEqlzsLsjH5JhDDkFuQW78MJfUZrswDzPg8M3yHsmsrj8UWbbdvmM8K01OMGNCaUlYnQW7GJaFkEzfHgQdjPHiLDDKOeBYkaoxI1A6j4OAcQ2Z4Bpl5JzSsGnx76HGElcSx/BfvCQtUY3@BuBWk45csxzzBKZxE7wREvpq2S3KpW6T4LRPbmB@9blwkrg@huuoaztZUcF4NBr3c0yI537bVBi1jSRpI/lQJA7uW0IV@tSgHVGRLkWGJUXpxXKepmMIQ5ffnHWk@h7xjpOTJPm426/FEpPp2HvqPOu86Lzx3uetfbdk2rVwrDTMZhB@4YUkRWA4wo0TgU4h9AeOV9k2KtykjFO0yRgfeHdUG@OngKS/r@GC0hDtQ9gB/YRHMWQf9zDsKIbZpz2MOIoR9mUPY45ijH21b4PKO1E8gRM/oTfMG@GNiQ@lur66nqfweXG5@Or8pwV8v7qYp4tvnWJDvUP5hvR9Xe@323Pid1jZJw41y5l9aW5gRSv3ZMB9kB9sw@C3uxJSOIFLYR/H4L4KrEkW9o34H8eoRKjsgwL69dMwxTSCe9dVjfbZlyihIm5fJ8E/).